# display ion-datetime when "next input" key is pressed in mobile keyboard

Tags: android, angular, forms, datepicker, ionic3

I have an angular reactive form in ionic 3 with an ion-datepicker component. When users click the "next input" button in the android keyboard, the datepicker is not focused, instead, the next input after the datepicker is focused.

[This is the button I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKu8K.png)

This is my form (simplified):

```
<form [formGroup]="formControls">
    <ion-card>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Precio actual</ion-label>
            <ion-input text-right formControlName="currentPrice"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Precio de transaccion</ion-label>
            <ion-input text-right formControlName="price"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Cantidad</ion-label>
            <ion-input text-right formControlName="quantity"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Valor total</ion-label>
            <ion-label text-right>{{transactiontotal | number: '1.0-6'}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Fecha de transacción</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" formControlName="date"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Notas</ion-label>
            <ion-textarea formControlName="notes"></ion-textarea>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card>

    <button ion-button full
            color="danger"
            *ngIf="transaction"
            (click)="onDeleteSelected()">
        Eliminar transacción
    </button>
</form>
```

When editing the `quantity` control, if the "next input" button is pressed the app focus the `notes` control.

Using `<input type="date">` reproduces the same problem

I assume this is a problem with cordova not realizing the ion-datetime is a form component or something in those lines. I really need a workaround, but I couldn't find a way to tell the interpreter that the component is a form component and should get focused like an ion-input.

A dirty hack I thought was to wrap the datepicker in an ion-input component which `on focus` don't show the keyboard and pop the native html5 datepicker instead. But is a hack, and is dirty

Comment: 3 years later. Still the same issue. @BlueKraken, have you found any fix?